# Language error when changed

Tags: errors, babel

I have a document template in Catalan  using `\usepackage[catalan]{babel}`. I want to write the document in Spanish, but when I change that line to `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` it throws an error:

> ./main.aux:3: Package babel Error: Unknown language `catalan'. Either you have
>    (babel) misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
>    (babel) or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,
>    (babel) install it or just rerun the file, respectively.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Do as the message says: "just rerun the file". Compile LaTeX again.

Comment: I am in Overleaf, how can I rerun the file?

Comment: I have never used it, but it looks like that it compiles automatically. If not, above the pdf preview, click "Manual" and then click "refresh preview".

Comment: I have compiled it and return the same error

Comment: you should be able to get overleaf to clear the aux file, but of not, just use `\usepackage[catalan,spanish]{babel}` so catalan is loaded but not used, should get you back on track

Comment: Ok, it works, and it changes some words to spanish. I would prefer to remove catalan language, but for now is ok

Comment: In overleaf, when there's an error click on the red error box on the top right and it should display a menu. Select the "compile from scratch" option and it will delete the `.aux` file before rebuilding the document